# in Rails 3.2, what is a safest way for multiple users to increment the same counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, locking

The ActiveRecord `Foo` model has a field `.hits` which is incremented each time an instance of Foo is displayed on a web page.

When an app has multiple web processes (multiple Heroku dynos), so multiple people might view the same page at the same time, what is the safest (but still performant) way to ensure two concurrent page views of the same instance of Foo does the right thing (eg, increments the counter twice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is the term "Atomic Incrementing"...

To answer your question, using the followings will get the job done:

- `increment_counter` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter
- `update_counters` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update_counters

A quick google returned this article which is sufficient at explaining why: http://www.alfreddd.com/2011/01/atomic-increment-in-rails.html

Answer (score -1):

Use this
    foo.increment!(hits, count)

Comment: According to one comment on the Apidock dpcs, increment!() does NOT handle concurrency.